# How to optimize NumPy array algebra for speed?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, octave

When I was translating a GNU Octave code into Python code, I realized that NumPy array algebra is significantly slower than that of Octave.

There is a huge performance difference especially in cumprod method. (For the following code, NumPy is around 80% slower than Octave, (Octave:0.4 sec, NumPy: 2.0 sec))

#### python

```
import numpy as np
from timer import Timer

n=1400000
k=30
matrix = np.eye(n, 2*k)
with Timer('speed test'):
    cumprodMatrix = np.cumprod(matrix, axis=0)
```

#### octave

```
n=1400000;
k=30;
matrix = eye(n, 2*k);
tic;cumprodMatrix = cumprod(matrix);toc
```

I would like to make my Python code as efficient as the Octave code.  Is there any way to calculate cumulative products along columns faster with NumPy?

Comment: The second question is totally off-topic as it asks to suggest an off-site resource.

Comment: Not sure the comparison is entirely fair, because if I remember correctly unlike numpy octave is column major. So you are asking numpy to sum along its 'difficult' (non-contiguous) axis whereas octave gets the 'easy' (contiguous, quite possibly heavily optimised) axis. What happens if you use the other axis?

Comment: I haven't done the benchmarks myself, but [`julia.org`](http://julialang.org/benchmarks/) suggests that your conclusions are either incorrect or they didn't try `cumprod`.

Comment: @paul-panzer Thank you for good information. I changed axis=0 to axis= 1 and tried the code again. This time they were almost the same speed. But whenever I tried rand, zeros and ones instead of eye to create a matrix, numpy was around 40% slower than octave. I don't know why this happens.

Comment: Time differences may be result of various coding differences.  The `numpy` version is a `ufunc`.  So it might be coded to conform to that category rather for optimal speed.  In my experience it's not a common operation.  `cumsum` on a 1d array to setup specialized indexing is more common.

Answer (score 1):

The NumPy code, if compiled with [Pythran](https://pythran.readthedocs.io), can be made faster, which gives some insights:

```
$ cat r.py
import numpy as np
#pythran export r(float[][])
def r(m):
    return np.cumprod(m, axis=0)

$ python -m perf timeit -s 'import numpy as np; n = 1400000; k = 30; matrix = np.eye(n, 2*k); import r' 'r.r(matrix)'
.....................
Median +- std dev: 1.45 sec +- 0.03 sec
$ python -m pythran.run r.py -DUSE_BOOST_SIMD -march=native
$ python -m perf timeit -s 'import numpy as np; n=1400000; k=30; matrix = np.eye(n, 2*k); import r' 'r.r(matrix)'                          .....................
Median +- std dev: 445 ms +- 11 ms
```

That's basically a x3 speedup by compiling the NumPy code to native code.

The benefits come from the use of AVX instructions, maybe Octave is doing so too?